# Gridview to .xlsx

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview

Wondering if someone could give me answer and some tip if it's possibly to export a grindview to a .xlsx (2007 versions of excel).

I have manage to transfer the grindview to .xls (2003 excel) but not to xlsx.

my code is:

Regards
Lime3003

```
Protected Sub ExportToExcel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + selReportName + " .xls")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "Application / vnd.openxmlformats - officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    'Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

    Using sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        gwResult.GridLines = GridLines.Both
        gwResult.RenderControl(hw)
        'style to format numbers to string
        Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode { } </style>"
        Response.Write(style)
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
        Response.Flush()
        Response.[End]()
    End Using
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control As Control)
    ' Verifies that the control is rendered 
End Sub
```

Comment: You are creating a html-table and then you're saving this html-text as an excel file. You cannot convert it to a real excel- file. I recommend [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim Schmelter said I was using EPPlus for export the dataview but I needed to change it to datatable.

```
    Protected Sub ExportToExcel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim dt As DataTable

    dt = dvData.ToTable

    'MsgBox(gwResult.HeaderRow.Cells.Count)
    Try
        Dim pck = New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage()
        Dim ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(selReportName)
        ws.Cells("A2").LoadFromDataTable(dt, True)

        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + selReportName + ".xlsx")
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray())
        'log error
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Response.[End]()

End Sub
```